# Do DNA supply houses maintain a watch list for dangerous oligos (Anthrax, Smallpox, etc.)?

Tags: dna, synthetic-biology, safety, gene-synthesis

The recent work by [DeLoache, et al.](http://www.nature.com/nchembio/journal/vaop/ncurrent/full/nchembio.1816.html) on a synthetic opiate-precursor production pathway in yeast has generated a lot of scare stories in the media about people homebrewing heroin as easily as they would beer.

In connection with DeLoache and coworkers' research, the [New York Times has claimed](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/05/19/health/a-way-to-brew-morphine-raises-concerns-over-regulation.html)

> Their DNA could be put on a watch list, as sequences for anthrax and smallpox are, so any attempt to buy them from DNA supply houses would raise flags.

I have never heard of such a watch list, and a thorough googling turned up nothing relevant save for the NYT article itself. Does this watch list exist?

Comment: I have heard about this before. But this is kind of pointless when you know how to handle and manipulate DNA. Besides that, it is not trivial to puzzle a virus together.

Comment: @chris `But this is kind of pointless when you know how to handle and manipulate DNA.` Yeah, that's my real question: how could such a list even work? How would it handle silent mutations? How would it handle SNPs, or other mutations easily fixed with PCR? Combinations of SNPs?

Comment: I think it will hold off people with no real knowledge. It won'T be a big hurdle for everybody else.

Comment: Cross-posted to [Skeptics](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/27801/do-commercial-dna-synthesis-labs-maintain-a-watch-list-of-dangerous-dna-sequen). In addition, while the smallpox genome might be within reach of gene synthesis, having an anthrax genome does not bring you any closer to synthesising an anthrax bacterium.

Comment: i encountered same question. nowadays you can order very big piece of dna custom-made. some viruses are <10Kb so they are easily synthesized. anthrax is 5Mb and smallpox is around 180Kb, so those are hard to produce in vitro

Comment: I guess the fear is not necessarily to have someone produce a viable virulent anthrax from a DNA sample, but to have them introduce virulence factors of those watched pathogens into previously harmless organisms they could easily buy and grow.

Comment: @aandreev While the whole bacterial genomes are far larger than a typical gene synthesizer can sell, DNA for the dangerous parts, like the botulism toxin protein, are small enough to be made. These could potentially be inserted into some other bacteria, like E. coli pretty easily. If you can do a little more work, you might be able to get into a cold or flu virus.

Comment: @aandreev Additionally, positive strand single stranded RNA viruses have genomic RNA that works as mRNA. If you had the DNA for the virus, and made the RNA through in vitro transcription, that RNA would be enough to infect cells and make virus, assuming you could get it into cells, which is still pretty hard. But maybe the RNA could be produced and stored more easily than the whole virus.

Comment: it seems to me that problem of producing virulent/pathogenic (i might mix terminology here) agents from scratch (via ordering DNA pieces and cloning) is medium to hard, but definitely doable. question is does companies check sequences and report to FBI

Comment: @aandreev I think they do. You could always get the smallpox sequence and submit it to genscript for synthesis. If the FBI comes knocking on your door, let us know before they send you to gitmo.

Comment: @user137 sure thing

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how generally such things are followed, but in at least one contract gene synthesis provider's [FAQ](http://www.genewiz.com/public/genesynthesis_FAQ.aspx), they address this issue, and mention two such government-provided resources:

> Q: Does GENEWIZ have a procedure in place to address potential biosecurity 
>           concerns for gene synthesis projects?
>
> GENEWIZ is fully aware of all risks and benefits associated with gene synthesis research. With the knowledge that gene synthesis technologies have the ability to enable de novo reconstruction of dangerous pathogens, GENEWIZ employs rigorous quality control policies and procedures to safeguard against abuse of the genes we synthesize. GENEWIZ actively monitors the Screening Framework Guidance for Synthetic Double-Stranded DNA Providers [[link]](http://www.phe.gov/Preparedness/legal/guidance/syndna/Pages/default.aspx), drafted by U.S. Department of Health and Human Services (HHS), as well as the [Select Agents and Toxins](http://www.selectagents.gov/) list put forth by the U.S. Government.